# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED using document.execCommand('ForeColor'... in Firefox 52.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, execcommand

I've got a contenteditable span in my own text editor. One can mark the text inside this span and then click on a button. Once the buttons was clicked there should be called the execCommand with 'ForeColor'. It worked fine and does so in Chrome. But if you mark the whole text and then click the button in Firefox then it comes to a NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED. Does anyone know why or how to avoid this?

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(event) {
  document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, '#f00');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>

<span contenteditable="true">Text</span><br /><br />
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I don't get an error in Firefox, but there is a difference in behavior between Chrome and Firefox when the entire text is selected -- in Firefox the color is not applied, while it is applied in Chrome. Probably doesn't matter, but are you also using Firefox 64-bit?

Comment: No, I'm using Firefox 32-bit. And the error is shown in FF developer tools and here even inside the snippet.